# Deserialize XML with ampersand using XmlSerializer()

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

The following code breaks when the XML has data like "Lord & Hogan". Any suggestions?
Thanks, Ken

```
    private T GetResponse<T>(String apiObject, String query)
    {
        //Deserialize XML into the type specified.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BuildRequestUri(apiObject, query));
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                return (T)ser.Deserialize(resp.GetResponseStream());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error = e.InnerException.ToString();
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 12, position 30.
I should mention that I have limited control over the source XML(users can add in ampersands without validation). Should I try to work with the response before I try to Deserialize? Thanks, Ken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119310/use-ampersand-in-cast-in-sql):

> A literal ampersand inside an XML tag
>   is not allowed by the XML standard,
>   and such a document will fail to parse
>   by any XML parser.

Other similar questions on StackOverflow:

- [How do I escape ampersands in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml)
- [Why can’t RSS handle the Ampersand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030102/why-cant-rss-handle-the-ampersand)
- [parsing XML with ampersand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473826/parsing-xml-with-ampersand)
- [Deserialize XML with ampersand using XmlSerializer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744046/deserialize-xml-with-ampersand-using-xmlserializer)
- there are more!

Answer (score 3):

you should XML-encode data like "Lord & Hogan". It should be encoded like this:

`"Lord &amp; Hogan"`

Answer (score 3):

`&` in xml should be replaced with `&amp;` otherwise it's invalid character.

Answer (score 2):

Here is function that can be used to replace all of the disallowed chars: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This also converts < and > to &lt and &gt and that bombs the deserialization :(