# Ampersand in XML url is not passed through

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm having hard-time fixing this little problem of ampersand (&) in the url... I'm serializing XML as shown below...

```
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(response));
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
    {
        response employeeResults = (response)ser.Deserialize(reader); //<<error when i pass with ampersand
    }
```

the above codes works fine if there is no `&` in the url otherwise it throws me an error (see below)

i have no problem serializing this url:

```
http://api.host.com/api/employees.xml/?&search=john
```

I'm having problem with this url:

```
http://api.host.com/api/employees.xml/?&max=20&page=10
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
`There is an error in XML document (1, 389).`
```

PS: I did tried passing `&#038;` and also tried with `&#38` or `#026` or `&amp;` - no luck.

Comment: Show the `response` class declaration and entire XML you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: Are you serializing or deserializing?

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XML isn't well-formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Api">
  <meta>
    <status>200</status>
    <message />
    <resultSet>
      <Checked>true</Checked>
    </resultSet>
    <pagination>
      <count>1</count>
      <page>1</page>
      <max>1</max>
      <curUri>http://api.host.com/employee.xml/?&max=5</curUri>
      <prevUri i:nil="true"/>
      <nextUri>http://api.host.com/employee.xml/?&max=5&page=2</nextUri>
    </pagination>
  </meta>
  <results i:type="ArrayOfemployeeItem">
    <empItem>
      <Id>CTR3242</Id>
      <name>john</name>
      ......
    </empItem>
  </results>
</response>
```

You must escape `&` character or put entire string in `CDATA`, e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Api">
  <meta>
    <status>200</status>
    <message />
    <resultSet>
      <Checked>true</Checked>
    </resultSet>
    <pagination>
      <count>1</count>
      <page>1</page>
      <max>1</max>
      <curUri><![CDATA[http://api.host.com/employee.xml/?&max=5]]></curUri>
      <prevUri i:nil="true"/>
      <nextUri><![CDATA[http://api.host.com/employee.xml/?&max=5&page=2]]></nextUri>
    </pagination>
  </meta>
  <results i:type="ArrayOfemployeeItem">
    <empItem>
      <Id>CTR3242</Id>
      <name>john</name>
      ......
    </empItem>
  </results>
</response>
```

If you are dealing with some third-party system and not able to get proper XML response, you have to do some pre-processing.

Maybe the simplest way is just replace all `&` with `&amp;` using `string.Replace` method.

Or use this regex `&(?!amp;)` to replace all `&` excluding correct ones like `&amp;`.

Comment: Replace `&` before deserialize? how would i do that? i am getting `var reader = xmlreader.create(url)`

Comment: @AbuHamzah, get you response as string using `WebClient.DownloadString`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx

Comment: so having ampersand in the xml is a bad thing? is there any site or blog that tells whats not allowed in xml that would be great so that i can tell the folks not to provide any characters that xml does not like. - thanks.

Comment: +1 (also string replace of any kind on "invalid XML" to make it well-formed is generally bad idea, forcing well-formed XML is much better). [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax) is the best place to find XML specification. See references from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328538/how-do-i-escape-ampersands-in-xml

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to wrap the Attribute with `<![CDATA[yourAttribute]]>`   ?
& is not allowed in xml

[deserialize-xml-with-ampersand-using-xmlserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744046/deserialize-xml-with-ampersand-using-xmlserializer)

Comment: where would you wrap before de-serializing ?

Comment: maybe you could pre-process the data before deserializing to remove the &?